# Как объявить пустой двумерный массив?

Tags: python

Как можно объявить двумерный массив размерностью x, y.

Так не работает:

```
arr = [][]
arr = [x][y]
```

Мне нужен именно пустой массив, т.к. дальше я буду вносить туда значения.
Нашел вариант с матрицей zeros, но его использовать не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно на основе списков создать:

```
x, y = 5, 3
array = [[0 for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
print(array)
# [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Пустой-строковой:

```
array = [["" for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
print(array)
# [['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать модуль Numpy - [numpy.empty()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty((x,y), dtype="float32")
```

---

```
In [47]: arr = np.empty((x,y), dtype="object")

In [48]: arr
Out[48]:
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)

In [49]: arr[1,1] = "XXXXX"

In [50]: arr
Out[50]:
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, 'XXXXX', None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: dtype="char" можно установить?

Comment: @Alexander, дополнил ответ...

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Вот так:

```
lst = [[]]
```